# RAM usage - Matlab operations

Tags: matlab, ram

Is there a way I can find out exactly how much RAM is used by performing various operations in Matlab?  For instance, say I want to find out how much RAM a 1000x1000 random matrix uses, or say I want to find out how much RAM a simple array entry uses, how can I go about this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the functions `whos` and `memory`?

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried the memory function, but not the whos function.  This turned out to help me with the information I needed.  Please enter this as a proper answer so that I may accept it.

Comment: Done. I have also included links to the documentation

Comment: Welcome! Actually it was an easy one :-)

Comment: In order not to confuse future readers. The question (and thus the answer posted by @LuisMendo) appears to be about the memory usage of variables, rather than that of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whos` to see how much memory each variable uses, or `whos a b c` if you only want to see variables `a`, `b` and `c`. See the [`documentation`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) for further options.

Also, `memory` gives general information about memory used by Matlab. See the [`documentation`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/memory.html) for more information.